# Enable File Stream SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sqlfilestream

I am trying to enable file stream on Microsoft SQL Server 2017, on a Windows Core 2019 Server.

I have changed the registry settings at the following location to enable it as there is no GUI. I set the value to 3

```
ServerName\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.InstanceName\MSSQLServer\Filestream.EnabledLevel
```

After This I restarted

I have also installed the latest Cumulative update ([20](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56128)) as I know there where issues with Driver signing.

After This I restarted

I am seeting the following Errors in the log file at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.InstanceName\MSSQL\Log

```
<{781FAE78-09AB-4EE5-B051-67747BDB19E3}>RsFxMgmtInitialize failed (the RsFx device is not found. Check if RsFx driver is started.): Error 0x80070002 (-2147024894)
2020-04-21 08:56:03.94 spid5s      FILESTREAM: failed to connect to kernel driver RsFx0503.
<{1038F43D-3391-45F7-B1B3-BADF26459429}>Failed to initialize CFsaShareFilter: Error 0x80070002 (-2147024894)

<{1038F43D-3391-45F7-B1B3-BADF26459429}>Failed to initialize CFsaShareFilter: Error 0x80070002 (-2147024894)

2020-04-21 08:56:03.94 spid5s      FILESTREAM: effective level = 0, configured level = 2.
2020-04-21 08:56:03.94 spid5s      FILESTREAM feature could not be initialized. The operating system Administrator must enable FILESTREAM on the instance using Configuration Manager.
```

SELECT @@VERSION

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU20) (KB4541283) - 14.0.3294.2 (X64)   Mar 13 2020 14:53:45   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```

I got this working on one server and cannot get it working on the second one.
There is also a version of sql 2019 on this box

Any help? Also any advice on getting this working on a cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used "computer management" and remotly connect to your core server. From there, you can enable FileStream and configure it.

This seemed to work better that the registry method

[image]
[image]